# I need help simulating a type of collision with hit locations and angles of cylinders without physics

Tags: collision-detection

I have this .gif, and it shows cylinders rotating on each other. It's done automatically with physics (UE4). It looks good and I am happy with it, but this only happens right 30% of the time.

The problem is UE4 physics are bad at this, and the top cylinder goes haywire 70% of the time. Would anyone know the name of an algorithm or something to achieve these types of collisions just based on the hit locations and angles of the cylinders colliding Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Sorry for not having concise info that wouldn't make sense without a .gif, but I couldn't explain it in a way that didn't take 50000000 words.

[image: Cyliners Collision]

[image: No collisions progress]

Comment: Could you show an example of both your expected case and actual case? Have you considered using a skeletal mesh?

Comment: These kinds of physics problems are pretty common in physics engines. Box2D, for instance, has stability issues for tall stacks of objects. You are definitely on the right track to avoid using physics to do this sort of thing.

Comment: LOL. Well... today I thought I'd get a gif of what goes wrong, and the physics behave. Literally nothing different except day and it seems fine now. I'm not trusting it and have decided to go the non physics way.

Comment: I have got some progress, check 2nd gif in the post if you are curious.
I have pretty good collision detection with movement and I have two sides of the cylinder so I can check if it needs to be rotated at the collision point also, I just have to work that part out :)